# SQL - Convert into Number & Remove Leading Zeros from Text Field

Tags: sql, ms-access

**BACKGROUND**

Table `Sales` has a text-field (despite not having any alpha-numeric values)`CustomerID` (e.g "`0010203`")

**OBJECTIVE**

- Convert `CustomerID` into a numeric value
- Remove leading zeros from `Customer ID`

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
SELECT
Val(Sales.CustomerID) as "Customer ID",
Sales.Revenue as "Revenue"
FROM Sales
```

**OUTPUT**

> "0"

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why isn't `CustomerID` being converted into a number when using Val() (see: [Microsoft Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Val-function-to-convert-text-values-to-numbers-05DCE9AC-1687-4EED-BC81-CC46DB2767A5))
2. If the field is being converted to a value (i.e "0", see: "output"), then why isn't the entire value being transformed?

Comment: I'm not sure why `Val()` isn't working, but you have other conversion options documented here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202

Comment: `Val` _will_ always return a number, so something else is going on. You may have to show some expanded code.